# Move meshes of several objects without affecting relative position

Tags: mesh

I've got a problem. I imported the single parts of a model as about 80 separate `.obj` files. The thing is, that the location of the objects is at {0,0,0} but the meshes are at ca {32,-149,1252} which makes them very far from the origin.

I need to keep the relative position between the meshes of the objects as they are part of a single model. Is it somehow possible to move all meshes without affecting their relative position? I need to get the model to the origin.

Maybe there is a different approach? I'm glad for every tips.

Note, I cannot combine the meshes into a single one because I need them separated.

### Edit: Minimal Example

- Create a new file with the standard cube
- Create an additional torus and move it 1 along the z axis (<kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>z</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd>)
- press Tab to get into Edit-Mode of the torus and then move the mesh 5 along the x-axis (<kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>5</kbd>)
- press Tab again to leave Edit-Mode and select the cube
- press Tab to get into Edit-Mode of the cube and then move the mesh 5 along the x-axis (<kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>5</kbd>)

After this, you should get something like shown in the following image:

[image]

Now, as you can see the location of the objects is `{0,0,0}` and `{0,0,1}`. This is similar to the situation I have with my imported `*.obj` files. It is vitally important the torus stays on top of the cube, but I want to move the *meshes* so that both objects are in the origin.

When I select all objects and move them together to the origin, then I get the situation, where for instance the cube is at {-5,0,0} but the mesh of the cube is at {5,0,0}.

[image]

You see that although my objects are now at the origin, the little coordinate system indicator is far behind it. Therefore, is there a way to move all meshes (instead of the objects) while maintaining their relative position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest one of two methods.

**Method 1**

- Move your 3D cursor to the center or your objects (that you want to move)
- Set origin of all the objects to 3D cursor.
- Now move the objects. (movements are based on origin. You can also set transform to "individual origins for a different effect.)

Note: Selecting all objects and making a group will make things easier. This way you can select the whole group easily by selecting one of the objects and pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> then selecting "group".

**Method 2**

- Create an empty
- parent those objects to the empty.
- Move the empty to the location you want.

Note: put the empty in the center of the object *before* parenting.

**Method 3**

*This method is for moving the vertices of **different objects** to the same place, when the origins are already in the desired location.*

- **Select** all the objects you would like to edit.
- **Snap** 3D cursor to *selected* (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>)
- *Set* **origin to *geometry***. (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or toolbar)
- **Snap** "selection to *Cursor* (offset)". (this operation is based on the origins, which are now at the centre of the geometry [mesh].)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I resolved it differently but I'm still interested in understanding it. The big problem is that *objects* are already at zero but the *meshes* are far off. I would like to move all meshes at once which doesn't seem to be possible. Do you know whether this is possible? AFAI can see, your method moves the objects, not the meshes that are contained in the objects.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. You want the vertices moved to the origin of the object. That is not quite possible, but something very similar is, and it may work for you (it is not quite precise, but it should help). I will add it to my answer.

Comment: I added method 3. I hope it works out for me. Tell me if it doesn't, and if you can, explain what needs to be done differently, but I'm not guaranteeing I'll know the answer. Still, I hope I can help. :) Thanks, Uncle Snail

Comment: I have added a small example for further reference, but as far as I can see, your 3rd method does what I want. The last step needs to be **Snap: Selection to Cursor (Offset)** but the important thing was the *origin to geometry* step. Thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for the correction. I didn't actually have Blender open. :P