# Transform multiple objects with (large) geographic coordinates to fit together

Tags: transforms, geometry, coordinates

I have a few objects with geographic coordinates (for instance, X can be 1 300 000), so they are far from the centre of the canvas.

I want to get them to the centre together, and also that they are within the bounds of the plane (the one that is there by default, sorry I don't know the name).

However, when I use the command `Shift` + `Control` + `Option` + `C` - `Geometry to Origin`, each is transformed separately and they don't fit anymore together (two objects that were touching each other are now displaced).

Furthermore, because of the size of the objects I need to scale them (0.01 of the original size suffices), but things get further degraded here.

How can I translate and scale the coordinates of all objects to local coordinates in such a way that the objects retain their relations?

**Edit: example**

The two objects in Meshlab with the original coordinates (the example before the transformation is in Meshlab because it conveniently adjusts the view to the extent of the objects):

[image]

After importing them to Blender and performing the command `Shift` + `Control` + `Option` + `C` - `Geometry to Origin` for both objects selected together, I get both in the centre overlapping with each other (I made separate screenshots with toggled visibility because one is over the other):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show some screenshots before and after transforming objects ?

Comment: @MrZak: I put screenshots for examples

Comment: Where are origin points of both the objects before performing *Geometry To Origin* ?

Comment: Do you mean the coordinates in the Transform/Location tab of the objects? They are both (0, 0, 0).

Comment: I meant [objects origins](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/origns.html) which can be visible as a small dot once object is selected. It's visible for one of your objects but it's not for another. Can you include a screenshot of objects after importing but *before* doing anything else ?

Comment: But after I import the models and select any of them there is nothing shown because the objects float somewhere far away (the coordinates are on the magnitude of millions of units). The second screenshot I put after the transformation doesn't show the point because I deselected the object. When I align the view to selected (Num .) I don't see the point, I just see the green outline of the selected geometry.

Comment: It means origin point is somewhere far away which might be not desirable. Moving objects respecting their local position should be possible in Object mode by moving their origin points to their geometry and `Shift`+`S` > *Selected to Cursor (Offset)* with 3D Cursor set where needed.

Comment: I did that, but how do I then move and scale all objects to the center (the default grid around 0,0,0) and retain their relations?

Comment: See if this help - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48320/move-meshes-of-several-objects-without-affecting-relative-position

Comment: Thank you @MrZak, that solved it. If you want you can make your comment as an answer so I can accept it.